# Shine some light on the [flashing] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [flashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flashing) tag has no guidance or wiki and it doesn’t appear to be used the same way in the 51 questions tagged with it. It’s either about flashing memory, flashing an image on purpose, or something flashing when it shouldn’t be.

Maybe the tag name should be more specific if it’s meant to be about flashing memory.

It’s not causing a lot of harm at 51 questions but it’s not helpful either.

Comment: Possible pun title: **Shine some light on the [flashing] tag**.

Comment: Maybe flashing is just the act of writing Adobe Flash code. I say nuke it. Preferably from orbit.

Comment: From reading the title of the first revision, I thought there was literally a tag with a CSS animation that causes it to flash.